# What is the series expression for (1+1/x)^x about x = \infty?

Tags: power-series, asymptotics, sequences-and-series

This seems like it must have been addressed somewhere already, but I cannot find it in any standard series tables.

I have the equation:

$f(z) = \left(1 + \frac{1}{z}\right)^z$.

What is the general form for the $n$th term of the series? That is, if I have

$f(z) \sim \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{c_n}{z^n}$

near $z = \infty$, what is the form of $c_n$?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Markus Brede proves the following formula in the paper ["On the convergence of the sequence defining Euler’s number"](http://www.springerlink.com/content/c1q27x0730v30hth/). Let $$\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)^z=\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{a_n}{z^n}$$
then we have
$$a_n=e\sum_{v=0}^n \frac{S(n+v,v)}{(n+v)!}\sum_{m=0}^{n-v}\frac{(-1)^m}{m!}$$
where $S(a,b)$ are Stirling numbers of the first kind. This shows that all coefficients are rational multiples of $e$. I found the article through [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C11%2C7%2C2447&sort=&language=english&go=Search).

Comment: Cool, who knew...

Comment: Thank you, that is excellent.

I should have gone straight to OEIS. I can't believe that I didn't think to do so. It turns out that I also needed another related series which was easily found there.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken, but the article can be found at [doi:10.1007/BF02985832](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02985832) ([Zbl 1207.11126](https://zbmath.org/1207.11126)).

Answer (score 8):

$\log f(z) = z \log(1+1/z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} z^{-k}$ as $z \to +\infty$, so $f(z)$ is the exponential of this sum.  See http://oeis.org/A055505 for the numerators and http://oeis.org/A055535 for the denominators of the coefficients.

Comment: There are two deleted answers which say the same thing (the authors deleted them because they don't actually answer the question as posed,unlike @Gjergji's answer...) 